# How to delete rows in Dataframe that contain attribute values in Series

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a series of employee ID's and a dataframe that uses employee id's. I would like to delete all the rows from the dataframe that have corresponding employee id's in the Series

I have this code which provides the Series

```py
resigned = employee_change['employee_id'][employee_change['type_of_termination'] == 'resignation']
```

I then have a dataframe called change_employee and would like to remove all rows of change_employee that has an employee_id in the series resigned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
change_employee = change_employee.loc[~change_employee['employee_id'].isin(resigned)]
```

Comment: couple of notes: I would use `.loc` accessor instead of bare brackets and you don't need the `.tolist` at the end